# Printing three dimension array value

Tags: php

I have an array it has three values fetched from db. I am not getting the print of every value.

```
$sort_query = "SELECT s_uniqid, mar_tot, mar_per FROM  `exam_record` WHERE  bat=`1314`"
$run_sort = mysql_query($sort_query);

while($selectedvalue = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_sort))
{   

$total[] = $selectedvalue;
}
Print_r($total);
```

the above query gives me the result as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [s_uniqid] => 1000017 [mar_tot] => 307 [mar_per] => 61.4 ) [1] => Array ( [s_uniqid] => 1000016 [mar_tot] => 288 [mar_per] => 57.6 ) [2] => Array ( [s_uniqid] => 1000015 [mar_tot] => 279 [mar_per] => 55.8 ) [3] => Array ( [s_uniqid] => 1000009 [mar_tot] => 269 [mar_per] => 53.8 ) [4] => Array ( [s_uniqid] => 1000010 [mar_tot] => 269 [mar_per] => 53.8 )
```

I want to print individual value of s_uniqid, mar_tot & mar_per... please suggest me.

Comment: you have a syntax error on line 1. You need a closing "

Comment: yah i editd.. just i type the code here. where this is not the error in my real code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```
foreach($total as $elem) {
    foreach($elem as $key => $val) {
        if($key == 's_uniqid')
            echo 'Unique ID: ' . $val;
        else if($key == 'mar_tot'
            echo 'Total Marks: ' . $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I worked like this but its giving the result of the full array. I want only the value of suppose s_uniqid. Can you tell me how.

Comment: Use if-else to check `$key`

Comment: i dont want to check any key just i want to print the values of s_uniqid and mar_tot

Answer (score 0):

something like this might do the trick:

```
$s_uniqids, $mar_tots, $mar_pers;
foreach($run_sort as $part) {
  $s_uniqids = $part['s_uniqid'];
  echo "s_uniqid: " .$part['s_uniqid'];

  $mar_tots = $part['mar_tot'];
  echo $mar_tot " .$part['mar_tot'];

  $mar_pers = $part['mar_per'];
  echo "mar_per: " .$part['mar_per'];
}
```

`$s_uniqids`, `$mar_tots` and `$mar_pers` are now arrays with the extracted values. You can loop through their individual values with a `foreach` loop like I used before.

Comment: again i have to use for loop to print the values of $s_uniqids??

Comment: `$s_uniqids` is an array. You could simply use the `print_r` function to print the array. But if you want to work with the individual values, you need a foreach loop: `foreach($s_uniqids as $s_uniqid) { .. }`. The values are accessible with the $s_uniqid variable inside the loop.

Comment: this the only way do i have to use three foreach loop. I want to print all the values using only one foreach loop. I think its possible but i am not getting the logic

Comment: What you could do is just print the values in the foreachloop in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING, use MYSQLI! MYSQL is DEPRECATED!!!**

```
$sort_query = "SELECT s_uniqid, mar_tot, mar_per FROM  `exam_record` WHERE  bat=`1314`"
$run_sort = mysqli_query($sort_query);

$suniquid = array();
while($selectedvalue = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sort))
{   
   $total[] = $selectedvalue;
   $suniquid[] = $selectedvalue['s_uniqid'];
}
print_r($total);

print_r($suniquid); //Prints values of s_uniqid
```

**EDITED:**

```
while($selectedvalue = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sort))
{ 
   echo $selectedvalue['s_uniqid'];
   echo $selectedvalue['mar_tot'];
   echo $selectedvalue['amr_per'];
}
```

And for example if you have two records this will result:

```
s_uniqid
mar_tot
amr_per
s_uniqid
mar_tot
amr_per
```

Otherwise you can do like this:

```
while($selectedvalue = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sort))
{
   $unique[] = $selectedvalue['s_uniqid'];
   $martot[] = $selectedvalue['mar_tot'];
   $amrper[] = $selectedvalue['amr_per'];
}

foreach($unique as $val)
{
  echo $val;
}

foreach($martot as $val)
{
  echo $val;
}

foreach($amrper as $val)
{
  echo $val;
}
```

And this will result (for example assuming again that you have two records):

```
s_uniqid
s_uniqid
mar_tot
mar_tot
amr_per
amr_per
```

Comment: dear i want to print continuously using foreach loop. Not the printing of an array. do i need to use three foreach loop to print all the values in S_uniqid, mar_tot, amr_per ?? also the syntax are same for mysqli. DO i just replace sql to sqli ?

Comment: Edited.

Anyway, yes, to fix the issue you only need to replace mysql_ with mysqli_ :)